# How can you execute a command outside of your current working directory in WinCvs?

Tags: perl, command, cvs, chdir, wincvs

I'm working on a Perl wrapper to execute commands within WinCvs.  I have been unable to find a way to execute Cvs commands without doing a `chdir` to the directory that you wish to execute the command on.

This is very annoying because it means that every time I want to do anything with Cvs in the perl script I need to get the current working directory, change directories to the Cvs path, execute my command, and then change directories back to the original working directory.

Is there a way to pass the path to a Cvs command so you can issue a command on a directory that you are not currently in?

For example, if my current working directory in my Perl script is `C:\test\` and I want to execute a Cvs `update` command on `C:\some_other_directory` how can I execute that command without doing a `chdir` to `C:\some_other_directory` first?

Example of how I would currently execute the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $cwd = cwd();
chdir "C:\some_other_directory" or die $!;
system 'cvs update';
chdir $cwd or die $!;
```

What I would like is to find a way to be able to pass "C:\some_other_directory" to the Cvs command directly and get rid of all of this `chdir` nonsense...

Comment: you could try with system 'cvs C:\some_other_directory\update';

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.  It gives you an "unknown command" error.

Comment: Not sure how I got a -1 here, the question and my goals are quite clear ... but oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flavio's answer works, but I also found this alternate solution.  It lets you change directories to issue the command, but is less dangerous than using `chdir` and less likely to leave you confused about what directory your script may be in at any given time.

The module [File::Chdir](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/File-chdir-0.1010/lib/File/chdir.pm) can solve the problem quite easily:

```
use File::Chdir;

# Set the current working directory
$CWD = '/foo/bar/baz';

# Locally scope this section
{
    local $CWD = '/some/other/directory';

    # Updates /some/other/directory
    system 'cvs update';
}

# current working directory is still /foo/bar/baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is by calling multiple commands in a single system call:

```
system("cd C:\some_other_directory && cvs update");
```